# Create excel from already created pdf

Tags: excel, pdfmake

For creating the PDF file, I am using pdfmake library. Below is the code sample for creating the pdf file using pdfmake library.
Does using the same objects that created the pdf, can be used in creating the excel file? Objects is very long, therefore wanted to reuse same objects for creating the excel file. Any leads will be really appreciated.

```
const dd = {
content: [
 body: [
 { text: "Address", color: "#231B12" },
 { text: Customer2 && Customer2.address, color: "gray" },
 { text: "Responsibility", color: "#231B12" },
 { text: Customer2 && Customer2.resp_org_name, color: "gray" }
    ]
  ]
}     
pdfMake.createPdf(dd).print();
```